# Connecting to .UDD with Transsoft driver from C# MVC Project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, odbc, database-connection

Hi there I am trying to connect to a database (Symology) with a **Transoft ODBC driver** but opening the connection simply hangs the project. I actually need to restart the application pool in IIS.

The DSN is an oddity called a .UDD file (Universal Data Dictionaries)

I can use MS Access to open the .UDD which then exposes the tables, so the connectivity is not an issue.

```
OdbcConnection connection = new OdbcConnection("DSN=test.udd;Uid=;Pwd=;");
connection.Open();
```

Has anyone successfully managed to do this, what am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.